# Powershell command passing quotes in -command

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have the following command in a bat file

```
start /b /WAIT Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -command  "%~dp0runFile.ps1" %USERNAME% %PASSWORD% %CHOSTNAME% %MODE% %FILENAME%"
```

This works when dp0 has no space in the path Ex: "C:/ProgramFiles/MyProgram"

Now when dp0 has a space in the path Ex: "C:/Program Files/My Program", it shows invalid command error.

I also tried

```
start /b /WAIT Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -command  ""%~dp0runFile.ps1" %USERNAME% %PASSWORD% %CHOSTNAME% %MODE% %FILENAME%"
```

but it shows Unexpected token error any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `-File` parameter instead:

```
start /b /WAIT Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -file "%~dp0runFile.ps1" %USERNAME% %PASSWORD% %CHOSTNAME% %MODE% %FILENAME%
```